# Troubles Imaging Library PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library, imaging

Here is my problem. The purpose of my program is to import an image to modify it with some effects. One of them is the "warhol effect", it multiplies the original image by 4. My problem is that I successfully multiply it by 4, but in red :

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJeym.png)

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA925.png)

(m and n correspond to the width and height of original image)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: it is better to copy paste the code into your question, instead of uploading an image of it. It is also better to include the image itself in the post, instead of providing a link to it.

That being said: I think your problem is the brackets around the `p` in the line with `putpixel`. The variable `p` is already a tuple with three elements in it. By placing brackets around it, the tuple you are giving to the function `putpixel` only contains one element, which is a tuple itself.

To be honest, I wouldn't even use `getpixel`, `putpixel` and a double loop, but the function `paste`.

```
img = PIL.image.open(ima)
img2 = PIL.image.new("RGB", (2*m, 2*n))
img2.paste(img, box=(0,0,m,n))
img2.paste(img, box=(m,0,2*m,n))
img2.paste(img, box=(0,n,m,2*n))
img2.paste(img, box=(m,n,2*m,2*n))
```

Or even better: adjust the images first, and then paste them in place.

Comment: First, thank you for answering : helped me a lot ! The problem now is to work with [0], [1] and [2] for modifying colors. How do I do without getpixel and putpixel ?

Comment: The code sample in my post should suffice for you to paste one image four times in a bigger image. You should replace your double for loop with this code sample, and then continue with `img2.save(...)`. If that does not work, please be as specific as possible what does not work.